# Cannot convert int to long

Tags: c#, .net

I created DB for one website and everything was working fine. For some reasons, I had to downgrade  from .Net Core 6 to .Net 5 and now I'm getting errors in migration files.
[Screenshot of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qb62v.png)

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried to change `1L` to `1` ?

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: Note that the actual error message is “cannot convert from 'long' to 'int'”, which is very different from what you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In EF Core 6, there are overloads for both `Int32` and `Int64` parameters of the `UseIdentityColumns` method. In EF Core 5, there is only one for `Int32`. So as mentioned in the comments, you need to change `1L` to simply `1`.